# Making named anchor links scroll to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my site I'm having issues with: http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/

It's a one page site and all the hyperlinks go to an area of the page using an anchor. Click a link such as:

```
<a href="#news">News</a>
```

and it will jump down to the section:

```
<li id="news" class="section_wrapper">
```

What is the best way using jQuery to make the jump to section a smooth scroll to section?

Many Thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use jquery plugin [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/)
it has a smooth scrool and variety of effects,
example of using it:

```
$.scrollTo( '#target-examples', 800, {easing:'elasout'} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a classic idea:

**[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ahezib/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
$('#nav li').click(function(){
  var liInd = $(this).index();
  var pagePos = $('.page').eq(liInd).position().top;

  $('body').stop(1).animate({scrollTop: pagePos},1000); 
});
```

Comment: Looks like animate doesn't like '-0'.  It wouldn't scroll back to page 1 - http://jsbin.com/ujisex/2/edit

Comment: @rkw ... may you please be more specific? whats wrong in my demo?

Comment: It may just be for Chrome.  Click on page1, then page2, then back to page1.  It has trouble scrolling back to page1.